# Visual C# DataGridView editing; have set all possible edit options; wont edit

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, phpmyadmin

I've spent about three weeks trying to find information on this and to no success.
DGV settings related to editing:
readonly is false on DGV
edit mode is keystroke on DGV.

code is here:
http://pastebin.com/eCv3iBcF

However, when trying to edit, nothing happens, the box just turns color from selection; the mouse doesn't change to recognize text, keystrokes do nothing.

What this is supposed to do (at least in my head and according to the tut):
Call the table.
Populate the DGV.
Allow edits on selected field by keystroke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the datasource of your BindingSource object as the SQLDataReader Object. This is a Read-Only Object.

> A DataReader is limited to being read-only and forward-only. That is,
>   the information retrieved from the database cannot be modified by the
>   DataReader, nor can the DataReader retrieve records in a random order.
>   Instead, a DataReader is limited to accessing the records in
>   sequential order, from the first one to the last one, one record at a
>   time."

You should use a DataAdpater instead and populate a DataTable.

You then use the DataTable as the Datasource for your BindingSource.

Alternativley, you cans tick with your DataReader like this:-

```
  using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                DataTable data = new DataTable();
                data.Load(reader);

            }
```

Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change your coding like below... it will help you...

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM catalog";
using (MySqlConnection con  = new MySqlConnection (connectionString))
{
 con.Open();
 using (MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query , con))
 {
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
  dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
 }
 con.Close();
}
```

Comment: A Binding Source does not make it Read-Only, The Fact that the DataReader object is Read-Only makes it uneditable. Your code will work, but there is no need to get rid of the BindingSource.

Comment: Thank you, this code and the information provided above has the DGV now editable.